# How to use different member variable names in a template?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2012, sfinae

**Edit:** Completely rewrote the question to address suggestions in comments

In a large project that I participate in, there are a lot of classes that wrap messages, events, etc.  They do not have a common ancestor and were (and still are) written by different people in different groups.

Most of these classes (or structs) have public members indicating error codes and descriptions.  However, since they are used mostly within a single group and conventions are pretty loose, some of them name the members `errStr`, while others use `errDesc`.

For example:

```
struct X {
  // stuff here...
  int errCode;
  std::string errStr;
};

struct Y {
  // stuff here...
  int errCode;
  std::string errDesc;
};
```

I am trying to write a function template that will accept an object and print out the value of the whatever member variable that it has.

In pseudocode:

```
template<typename T>
bool logError(T const& x)
{
  if (x.errCode == 0)
    return true;

  // if (T::errStr exists)
  //   log(x.errStr);
  // else if (T::errDesc exists)
  //   log(x.errDesc);
  return false;
}
```

What complicates matters is that the compiler that we use is VS2012, which is not fully C++11 compliant.

I have been messing with std::enable_if, std::is_same, etc for a while and so far the only result is an impressive collection of different compiler errors.

I was pointed to [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Member_Detector) by @T.C.
While it turned out to work quite well, it appears clunky and I was wondering if it can be simplified, or another solution offered, using the C++11 features that VS2012 supports.

Thank you!

Comment: You are using a relatively old compiler. Although this is a trivial excersize in SFINAE, I don't know how well your old compiler will be able to deal with it. If you're truly interested in becoming proficient in C++, you need a better C++ compiler, preferrably gcc 5.3, or later, on Linux. Or maybe its Windows port.

Comment: This is the compiler used in my workplace so I am stuck with it.

Comment: Well, then, then my recommendation is to find some other way to accomplish whatever you intended to accomplish using this approach. If you are required to use crippled, obsolete tools, you have no other viable options. This old compiler might be able to support some forms of SFINAE, but I don't want to waste your time and post something that will turn out not to be usable with your compiler. Make X and Y derive from a superclass that defines a virtual print(), and implement print() in your X and Y to print whatever member variable it has, then use that in your f().

Comment: If I could modify X and Y, I would not be asking this question.

Comment: This is trivial in real C++11, but VS2012...ugh. You can try [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Member_Detector). No guarantees whether it will work, though.

Comment: "Hello, I would like to have a nice dinner, but my hands are handcuffed behind my back, what can I do?"

Comment: "Hello, I am unable to offer any useful advice, so I will just amuse myself by pointless trolling"

Comment: @T.C., please submit as answer.  That incomprehensible ugliness worked!

Answer (score 0):

In principle you can use SFINAE to detect the relevant member, but with C++03 (your compiler's standard) this yields complex, verbose code that's easy to break by maintenance – I give a complete example at the end below. The relevant techniques are covered in umpteen places on the web. E.g. I googled "c++ detect data member SFINAE" and hey presto, some GitHub code, and other examples. The ability to find information on the web, including basic googling, is very important to a developer. So, just try it.

An IMO more practical approach – because it's much simpler code that does not introduce maintenance problems and that goes in the direction you want the code to evolve – is to simply define overloads of an accessor function, one per class, like this:

```
string errorMessageOf( X const& o ) { return o.errStr; }
string errorMessageOf( Y const& o ) { return o.errDsc; }
```

Not everything needs to be a template.

Ordinary overloads are nice.

Your desired function template is then

```
template< class Type >
bool logError( Type const& x )
{
    if (x.errCode == 0) return true;    // A really dangerous thing to do
    // Especially in Windows error code 0 a.k.a. NOERROR etc. is
    // sometimes returned by GetLastError for a genuine failure. You
    // should better treat it as "unknown cause".

    clog << errorMessageOf( x ) << endl;
    return not clog.fail();    // The return value is unspecified.
}
```

---

Example of instead using C++03 SFINAE, with code that works with Visual C++ 2012, and supporting an arbitrary number of names for the error message data member:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string>

//----------------------------------------------- Machinery:

namespace reusable {
    typedef ptrdiff_t Size;

    template< Size n >
    struct SizeCarrier_ { char nPlusOne[n + 1]; };

    template< class Type, Type >
    struct TypeFrom_;
}  // namespace reusable

namespace my{
    using std::string;

    namespace impl {
        using reusable::SizeCarrier_;
        using reusable::TypeFrom_;

        struct ErrorMsgMemberId { enum Enum{ noSuch, errStrName, errDescName }; };

        template< class Type >
        class ErrorMsgMemberId_
        {
        private:
            template< class U >
            static SizeCarrier_< ErrorMsgMemberId::errStrName >
            memberId( TypeFrom_<string U::*, &U::errStr>* );

            template< class U >
            static SizeCarrier_<ErrorMsgMemberId::errDescName>
            memberId( TypeFrom_<string U::*, &U::errDesc>* );

            template< class U >
            static SizeCarrier_<ErrorMsgMemberId::noSuch>
            memberId( ... );

        public:
            static ErrorMsgMemberId::Enum const value = static_cast<ErrorMsgMemberId::Enum>(
                sizeof( memberId< Type >( 0 ).nPlusOne ) - 1
                );
        };

        template< ErrorMsgMemberId::Enum kind >
        struct ErrorMsgFunc_;

        template<>
        struct ErrorMsgFunc_< ErrorMsgMemberId::errStrName >
        {
            template< class Type >
            string operator()( Type const& o ) const
            { return o.errStr; }
        };

        template<>
        struct ErrorMsgFunc_< ErrorMsgMemberId::errDescName >
        {
            template< class Type >
            string operator()( Type const& o ) const
            { return o.errDesc; }
        };

    }  // namespace impl

    template< class Type >
    string errorMsgOf( Type const& o )
    {
        static impl::ErrorMsgMemberId::Enum const member_id =
            impl::ErrorMsgMemberId_< Type >::value;
        return impl::ErrorMsgFunc_< member_id >()( o );
    }

}  // namespace my


//----------------------------------------------- Example usage:

struct X {
  // stuff here...
  int errCode;
  std::string errStr;
};

struct Y {
  // stuff here...
  int errCode;
  std::string errDesc;
};

struct Z {
  // stuff here...
  int errCode;
}; 

int main()
{
    X const x = { 1, "X::errStr" };
    Y const y = { 2, "Y::errDesc" };
    Z const z = { 3 };

    using namespace std;
    cout << my::errorMsgOf( x ) << endl;
    cout << my::errorMsgOf( y ) << endl;
    //cout << my::errorMsgOf( z ) << endl;      //! Fails with 'noSuch' in message.
}
```

Comment: An overload does not work when I have an unknown number of classes with an "aString" member and another unknown number with a "myString" member

Comment: @AlexO: This lack of information about your own code or the code you're using, is curious and indicates that the problem description leaves out some very significant part.

Comment: I will add to the description

Comment: @AlexO: I updated the answer accordingly. But I still think there's something something about not knowing all classes. For I cannot imagine that a large application is structured as mainly templated code.